# Access to field results in dereference of a null pointer

Tags: c++

I get this warning when analyzing the code with XCode 4.6 and I don't get it.

```
    VanishingPointInfo* vpClosestToCenterLine = NULL;
    for (vector<VanishingPointInfo>::iterator vpInfo = lineCrossings.begin(); vpInfo != lineCrossings.end(); vpInfo++)
    {
        if (vpClosestToCenterLine == NULL || vpInfo->diffToMiddle < vpClosestToCenterLine->diffToMiddle)
        {
            vpClosestToCenterLine = &(*vpInfo);
        }
    }
```

XCode complains that the access to `vpInfo->diffToMiddle` results in a dereference of a `NULL` pointer. But that is the iterator...

Comment: 1. What is vpInfo? 2. Just out of curiosity, try `(*vpInfo).` instead of `vpInfo->`

Comment: Are you sure it's not `vpClosestToCenterLine->diffToMiddle` because it doesn't know if it's not null any more?

Comment: @Djon: I don't think, because it can't enter to the second part of the `||` of the `if` if it's `NULL`.

Comment: Yes but I didn't know if the compiler would know that, since you explicitly declare it NULL just before. On a side note, if you are using a C++11 compiler, you might want to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: What is `diffToMiddle`?

Comment: Consider the (exceptional) case when `vpClosestToCenterLine` is not NULL but `vpInfo` is NULL. This is what XCode is thinking and warning you about.

Comment: @Sarwar Erfan: I think that `vpInfo` can't be `NULL` since `vector::begin` returns an iterator:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/

Comment: The XCode is not thinking that.. this is an code analysis report of XCode, not an actual warning.. That's why I wrote "this is what **XCode** is thinking..."

Comment: But how can XCode think that since it knows that `vector::begin` returns an iterator for sure?

Comment: diffToMiddle is an int. I tried (*vpInfo).diffToMiddle and I still get the dereference error. Yes vpinfo cant be null.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is flagging the message to warn that the is an error if vpInfo has a null value, if it does then the substructures inside vpInfo are all invalid. To fix the warning you can put an existence check before going through the logic requiring access to the substructures. ....

```
   if (vpInfo) {
        VanishingPointInfo* vpClosestToCenterLine = NULL;
for (vector<VanishingPointInfo>::iterator vpInfo = lineCrossings.begin(); vpInfo != lineCrossings.end(); vpInfo++)
{
    if (vpClosestToCenterLine == NULL || vpInfo->diffToMiddle < vpClosestToCenterLine->diffToMiddle)
    {
        vpClosestToCenterLine = &(*vpInfo);
    }
}}
```

Comment: `vpInfo` can't be null within the `for` loop block.

Comment: that maybe true but the new compiler/analyzer does not know that and expects an existence check. I got a lot of these messages with a 3rd party library (pnglib), earlier Xcode versions do not check for this but they do now.